# Winforms and drawing complicated charts

Tags: winforms, drawing

I need to draw complicated chart (something like in the picture).

[image]

As I am developing WinForms app, I would like to show that chart in my window. What I am looking for is some library that would allow me to do that. I found ChartControl, but it seems to be a bit primitive and insufficient for my needs.

Do you know some libraries that would let me draw complex charts? Compatibility with winForms is not priority, but I would like to generate that chart using C#.

Comment: this is more of a random drawing than a chart.

Comment: That's Schaeffler chart, usefull for welders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From within `WinForms` you can use the `System.Drawing` namespace to do your own drawing.

For a chart as complex as this, there is a great likelihood that you will be able to write your own code to draw it in less time than it will take you to learn some existing library (which was built primarily for bar charts) and coerce it to draw such a chart for you.